# How to create complex objects using factory design pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependencies, factory

Hello i have to create a complex object , and i wanted to use the factory pattern for it.However i do not know what to do with the additional dependencies that the object needs in order to be created.

**Dependencies**

```
public class SomeService
{
}
public class SomeOtherService
{
}
```

**Hierarchy**

```
public abstract class NeededObjectBase
{
  public readonly int Type {get;set;}  //id selected by the factory

  public abstract void DoSomething();
}
public class A:NeededObjectBase
{
   private SomeService service;
   A(SomeService service){ this.service=service;}
   public override void DoSomething(){}
}
public class B:NeededObjectBase
{
   public B(SomeService service,SomeOtherService otherService){
       this.service=service;
       this.otherService=otherService
   }
   public SomeOtherService service;
   public SomeOtherService otherService;
   public override void DoSomething(){}
}
```

**Factory**

```
public class Factory
{
   public static NeededObjectBase CreateInstance(int type)
   {
       switch(type)
       {
        case 0:return new A();  //this would need SomeService => new A(someService)
        case 1:return new B();   // this would need SomeService & SomeOtherService => new B(someService,someOtherService);
        default: return new A();
       }
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public class Aggregate
{
   private SomeService s1;
   private SomeOtherService s2;
   public void UseNeededObject(int type)
   {
     NeededObjectBase neededObject=Factory.CreateInstance(type);
     neededObject.DoSomething();
   }
}
```

If you look in the code things happen like this:
I have an `Aggregate` class where i keep my **dependencies**.
Inside its method i  use the `Factory` based on the `type` parameter in order to create the right object.
However i do not know what to do with the dependencies.Should the factory get all the required dependencies in order to create the objects ?

So basically i do not know who should keep the dependencies for object creation.The factory makes the selection but how does it provide the right dependencies in order to instantiate the selection ?

**P.S** I  would need somehow to first make the selection based on the parameter and retrieve `something` from the factory and then that something to get its dependencies in order to create the final object.

Comment: May want to look at the builder pattern https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder/csharp/example

Comment: This is why DI is more general and DI implementations are not simple at all. You have a dependency graph, that you have to handle yourself either by reflecting the constructor or using some metadata. Or, do it manually with hardcoding (builder and factory are actually hardcoding). But better use DI and a DI toolkit library like Unity (Some literature: https://www.codementor.io/mrfojo/c-with-dependency-injection-k2qfxbb8q).

Comment: You are indeed right that i would need DI , but how can i use DI when instantiating an object  by myself ?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian well, you should not. But if you still want to, in Unity you can use `RegisterInstance` to register an already constructed instance. But if applicable, better use `RegisterSingleton` and let the container work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good way of doing this is to use a DI library and to then inject whatever container it provides into the factory; the factory is then only deciding based on the passed parameters what type it should return, and then delegating to the container to construct that object for return.

This has some benefits

- It lets you separate the lifecycle of these dependent objects (and indeed, the constructed objects) from the factory
- It decouples the factory from having to know how to construct all the possible object graphs it provides and lets it focus on making the decision on *what* to build, not *how* to build it

e.g.

```
public class SimpleFoo: Foo
{
    public  SimpleFoo(IServiceA a){...}
}

public class ComplexFoo: Foo
{
    public  ComplexFoo(IServiceA a, IServiceB b){...}
}

public class DegenerateFoo: Foo
{
    public DegenerateFoo(){..does nothing...}
}

public class FooFactory
{    
    readonly IContainer _container;
    public void FooFactory(IContainer container){_container=container;}

    public Foo GetAFoo(int type)
    {
       switch (type)
       {
            case 0:
                return _container.Get<SimpleFoo>();
            case 1:
                return _container.Get<ComplexFoo>();
            default:
                //unknown case, return some kind of Foo that does nothing
                return _container.get<DegenerateFoo>();
       }
    }
}
```

Your container, meanwhile, would have been separately configured somewhere else in the application's "Composition Root" to know how to resolve the object graphs (the following is pseudocode only)

```
container.RegisterTransient<IServiceA, ServiceAImplementation>();
container.RegisterSingleton<IServiceB, ServiceBImplementation>();
```

In this case we're configuring that any `IServiceA` injection is a new object instance each time it is requested; whereas `IServiceB` injections will be a single shared instance that the container takes care of creating once and doling out on request. Of course this is just an example of how you might configure these, ultimately you know best how you need to configure the lifetimes of these dependencies.

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Yes but how would i be able to register the container inside my `Aggregate` class.I thought that you are able to register stuff only in the `Startup` class not anywhere else.What you are saying is indeed what i need.Someone (in my case the `Aggregate` class)  to have access to all dependencies and register all my implementations.In your example i would have a class that uses the `FooFactory.GetAFoo` and in that class i need to register all the implementations (and not in the `Startup`)

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian - well you would register the Aggregate type with the container as well...of course you will need to declare its dependencies publicly (via its constructor) but then the container will figure out how to create one...in this case the dependency is on the factory itself. How that aggregate gets instantiated depends on where it's being used - if this is asp.net then wherever you declare it as a depdendency, then DI will take care of it. If it's a forms app or a console app then at some point you will have to manually ask the container for an instance of it.